# C# Mysql connection problems - connection attempt failed

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I get the following error when loading my C# ASP.net page.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a    period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>
> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not  properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected  host has failed to
>   respond] System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags  socketFlags) +6528783
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) +130
>
> [IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond.]
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) +296  MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +47
>
> [TimeoutException: Unable to read data from the transport connection:
>   A connection attempt    failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.] 
>   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count) +204  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +128 
>   System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   +262  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +42
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket() +64
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +32
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +253
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) +208   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +625 
>   UoRLive.iPadLayout.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Corbin
>   Spicer\Documents\FinalYearProject\UoRLive\UoRLive\iPadLayout.aspx.cs:92
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51  System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54 
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

Background:

The script runs perfectly on a local machine when trying to connect to a local MYSQL database, however I have moved it on to smarterasp.net, set up another MYSQL database and now am getting this error message.

The only thing that has changed is the connection string:

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
    {


        string connStr = String.Format("server={0};user id={1}; password={2}; port={3};" +
                 "database=MYDATABASE_resources; pooling=false", "SQL5011.Smarterasp.net",
                 "DMYDATABSE_resources_admin", "MyPassword", "1433");


        return connStr;
    }
```

The details are 100% correct and I have checked them by connecting to the server using MYsql workbench.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you could connect to MySql  on the remote server via Workbench using that port?

Comment: @Corbin Spicer: were you planning on adding more information to your question?

Answer (score 4):

`1433` is the default SQL Server port.

`3306` is the default MySQL port.